# Trying to add unregistered COM component

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to add a reference to a non-.NET DLL to my project, but I get the following error:

> A reference to 'C:\path\to\dll\tlbinf32.dll' could not be added. Could not register the ActiveX type library 'C:\path\to\dll\tlbinf32.dll\1'. This is not a .NET assembly.

This DLL is not registered on my machine, but AFAIK I shouldn't need to register it.

I'm getting the same error from both VS 2019 and VS 2017.

I can add a reference to this DLL in the VBA IDE, not from the list of registered type libraries, but using the **Browse...** button.

How can I resolve this?

**Update**

I tried to run Visual Studio as an administrator; I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `tlbinf32.dll` is a COM dll that should be registered, and it most likely already is. You add reference to COM dlls from the [COM tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019#com-tab)

Comment: @GSerg It doesn't appear to be registered.

Comment: The IDE tries to maximize the odds that you can debug your program.  Which requires the component to be registered.  Since it is not, it tries to do it for you.  Kabloom when VS doesn't run elevated.  If you don't want to debug your program then run Tlbimp.exe instead to generate the interop library.  Okay on a build server.  You can check-in that library, the component is never going to change again.

Comment: @HansPassant Running VS as administrator doesn't help.

Comment: Well, that was not my advice.  Get a good answer by explaining why you want to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant _Kabloom when VS doesn't run elevated._ seems to imply that running VS elevated should work around the problem. Unless VS executes `regsvr32` under different permissions?

Comment: @HansPassant _Get a good answer by explaining why you want to do this._ I'm trying to reopen an old project of mine. I was under the impression that it isn't necessary to register a COM component to use it from a .NET Framework project, and I seem to recall it "just working" in the past.

Comment: Perhaps I am being thick here.. have you tried registering the com dll the good old fashion way with regsvr32 just to see what happens? As an administrator: regsvr32 [path_to_dll]  ??  Again.. I might not be thinking this through.. :P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I was trying to avoid doing that, because this is only a one-time use of this project (and I know I can unregister once I'm finished). But that is what I did in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using **regsvr32** to register the dll worked for me.

Thanks to Señor CMasMas for suggesting this.